# Importing a library with cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to use this library in my ios project:https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift

I am trying to use with cocoapods.I created a `Podfile` in my project library.

This is my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 2.2.2’
```

When I run, I am getting following errors:

```
SyntaxError - /Users/.../Documents/SwiftSonSurum/Podfile:4: unterminated string meets end of file
[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

It appears to have originated from your Podfile at line 4.
```

How can I fixt these errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last quote of your podfile should be a `'` instead of a `’`

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I can't build the project.I am getting this error: http://prntscr.com/70d0ma Do you know how can I fix this ?

Comment: No, I didn't. What should I do ?

Comment: I opened .xcworkspace file then I tried to compile my project but i am getting these errors: http://prntscr.com/70ehie do you know how can i fix ?